# How Do I getText().toString() a TextView Using RemoteViews?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-remoteview

I'm developing a widget for the first time, and remoteviews is a bit confusing compared to building an app.

I understand this part...

```
RemoteViews views = new Remoteviews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget_layout);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.myTV, "Hello World");
```

Now the next is a bit complex for me. I want the button that I have on the widget to pass the TextView text and display it on a toast.

Here's what I started...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, myReceiver.class);
PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myButton, myPendingIntent);
```

My Class (This is where I need help!)

```
public static class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
Toast.makeText(context, (HELP! I need to getText().toString() from the R.id.myTV), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Thanks! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the text you want to display to the intent via putStringExtra method and then extract the extra string like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(check-your-desired-action-here)) {
            String textThatYouWantToDisplay = intent.getStringExtra("name-of-the-desired-item");
            Toast.makeText(context,textThatYouWantToDisplay , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

for more info:

[this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/StackWidget) sample widget app from google

[Build an app widget android document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets)

Intent getStringExtra [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getStringExtra(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks anyways Abhishek Choudhary, but unfortunately, I am not understanding your answer. I read through the links, it's too complex for me to comprehend. I don't know what you mean by check-your-desired-action-here and name-of-the-desired-item.

Comment: check-your-desired-action-here and name-of-the-desired-item were the hints I was giving you. Like a placeholder you know. Glad I could help you. Cheers!!